# Problem whit Solidify "X"-ing my mesh

Tags: modeling, modifiers

[image]

The mesh should be whit same curve as is the selected faces, but the mesh created by solidify modifier makes the same location on the new panel of mesh created in "X" shape. Is there a way to fix it?
[image]

Comment: Either reduce Solidify Thickness, or play with Clamping value/Offset.

Comment: Any other tips? Maybe i have to manually merge the nodes at interesction?